# Best way to create C++ dynamic library and use it on Mac and XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, dll, dylib

I'm starting a game project where I'm going to have both the game code and the engine code separated into different projects (into one workspace on XCode).

What's the best way to build and ship the engine code and achieve a good workflow on developing and debugging the game code, together with the engine code?

I started thinking about building the engine code as a dynamic library (`.dylib`), however I understand that the engine headers need to be included on the game code, as well as the dynamic library itself, and I'm not entirely sure about the best practices regarding that.